# How to make AWS Codebuild prompt for confirmation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am creating a Codebuild project in order to apply latest terraform configuration.

A minor problem is that if there are too many changes/destroys, I dont want they to be applied.

However, as far as I know, Codebuild does not allow to input confirmation in middle of execution.

Anyone have a suggestion or workaround idea would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build in mechanism for that in CB. Instead, generally, you would use CB within your CodePipeline (CP) which has [manual approval action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/approvals-action-add.html).

Thus in your case, you could consider using CP and have two CB actions: first to run `plan`, then CP would use `manual approval action` to get approval to execute the plan, and second CB action which would actually `apply` the changes if approval was given.

Comment: As his topic, I think he didn't use CodePipeline. If he has CP, there is a way to add manual approve as your answer.

Comment: @Franxihidro  Thanks. I updated answer that CB does not have such mechanism and recommend to consider CP.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, i will consider codepipeline as your recommendation

Comment: @TiếnVũ No problem. Glad I could help.